# Print the content of each file in a tar archive

Tags: tar

Listing the files in a gzipped tar file is easy with `xvfz`:

```
$ date >> a
$ date >> b

$ cat a b
Sun Sep 24 14:27:01 IDT 2017
Sun Sep 24 14:27:05 IDT 2017

$ cat dates.tgz | tar xfvz -
x a
x b
```

Is there an elegant way to print the content of each file in the tar, in the spirit of:

```
$ cat dates.tgz | tar <?> -
a:
Sun Sep 24 14:27:01 IDT 2017
b:
Sun Sep 24 14:27:05 IDT 2017
```

Comment: if all the files are in the same folder
`for i in *; tar czvf $i.tar.gz $i; done`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work:

```
tar --wildcards --to-stdout -xvf archive.tar.gz './*'
```

Note that there may be issues with `'./*'` part: I'm not sure how exactly tar matches paths. Obviously, if you have an absolute path in the archive, this won't match, but, again, I'm not sure if just `'*'` is a better option.

I believe that some tar implementations will accept `-O` as well / in place of `--to-stdout`. I'm not sure if `--wildcards` is exclusive to GNU implementation.

---

Here's the version that avoids using `--wildcards`

```
tar -xOvf archive.tar.gz $(tar -tf archive.tar.gz)
```

Comment: Only works with GNU `tar`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm looking at the man page right now, but I can neither confirm nor disprove this. I don't have an alternative implementation handy, but from the looks of it, I tend to agree.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using GNU `tar` with `-O` or `--to-stdout`, there is no good way of doing this in any portable way:

```
$ tar -tvzf dates.tgz
-rw-r--r-- kk/wheel         30 2017-09-25 08:41 a
-rw-r--r-- kk/wheel         30 2017-09-25 08:41 b

$ tar -Ov -xzf dates.tgz
a
Mon Sep 25 08:41:51 CEST 2017
b
Mon Sep 25 08:41:53 CEST 2017
```

The BSD `tar` implementation (on OpenBSD) does not support a `-O` flag, and the standard `pax` archiver is also unable to extract files to standard output.

Comment: FreeBSD and NetBSD `tar` (or libarchive's portable `bsdtar`) do support `-O`. Only OpenBSD seems not to support it yet. Note that it doesn't print the content of  hard or soft links in the archive (and obviously not fifos, devices...)

Comment: `bsdtar`'s output (at least in 3.2.1) is not properly formatted when `-O` is combined with `-v` or `-vv` though (as needed by the OP to get the name of the file).

Comment: See also `bsdtar -xOf - -'s/.*/ /pHS'` with bsdtar or FreeBSD tar for a better formatted output.